# Вытащить изображение из Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

При нажатии на кнопку на сайте генерируется изображение и фронт переодически опрашивает бекенд, проверяет готово ли изображение. Когда изображение готово бек возвращает ссылку на изображение и оно подгружается на фронт.
Мне надо скачать это изображение, я написал скрипт на Python с использованием Selenium, но я получаю ссылку на изображение уже из объекта image в коде страницы, а потом при попытке скачать это изображение по ссылке выдается ошибка "Изображение не найдено", видимо оно доступно для скачивания лишь раз при генерации. Вопрос могу ли я вытянуть это изображение как то из Selenium, ведь оно 100% скачивается для отображения на страничке.

Comment: Маловато данных для ответа. Самый простой - сделайте скрин изображения.